Installing Tk on Strawberry Perl leads to compiler errors
I am running Strawberry Perl 5, version 38, subversion 0 (v5.38.0) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
I downloaded the latest version from CPAN (Tk-804.036) and tried
perl makefile.pl
but got a number of compiler errors. Following the thread “Tk build fails (Perl 5.36 sp536 20230420)#98" from @HaraldJoerg I made the following changes in the code:

Changed all occurrences of
ControlMask
to
ControlMask_BUGBUG
in all .c and .h files in the project, i.e. pTk\mTk\xlib\X11\X.h, pTk\tkBind.c, pTk\tkWinKey.c, pTk\tkWinPointer.c, pTk\tkWinX.c, pTk\mTk\generic\tkBind.c

Changed all occurrences of case SVt_IV: to
#ifdef HAS_REAL_SVT_RV
case SVt_RV:
#endif


in all files containing the string SVt_RV, i.e config/svtrv.c, Event\pTkCallback.c

Changed "op_pmdynflags" to "op_pmflags" and deleted the line containing "op_pmpermflags" in file config/pmop.c
I was then able to make realclean and then do perl makefile.pl to get a clean compile except for a minor warning from the file config/Hstrdup.c about config/Hstrdup.c: implicit declaration of function 'exit'.

However make test still throws many concerning warnings about casting pointers to the wrong size integers, etc. I did make -i test and make -i install and then tried to run the following program (from the book by Lidie and Walsh):
use Tk;
my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->title("Hello World");
$mw->Button( -text => "Done", -command => sub { exit} ) -> pack;
MainLoop;

This program silently does nothing (returns me to the command prompt without opening a window).
I am new to the arena of editing open-source software like Tk, and do not know how to approach officially submitting what I did to cure the compile errors (not sure why the main branch of Tk is broken in my environment – it must have worked somewhere!). But it still appears broken in some way, even after my changes. I think that the warnings about casting pointers during the test part does not necessarily reflect badly on the code being tested, but only on the test code itself, but I could be wrong.
Does anyone know of a working version of Strawberry Perl that plays well with a working version of Tk?

cpan Tk does not work? Usually how I install a module on windows.

See also: https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/issues/98

cpan Tk results in the error described by  github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/issues/98:  ../pTk/mTk/xlib/X11/X.h:182:34: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
182 | #define ControlMask             (1<<2) ; @Håkon Hægland;
I will try to apply the fix noted.

Clone perl-tk from https://github.com/eserte/perl-tk.git | Checkout the master branch | Apply the patch from https://github.com/eserte/perl-tk/files/14965386/win32_patch.txt to pTk/mTk/xlib/X11/X.h   - Tested on SP-5.38.2.2 with all tests passing

Yes, applying the patch to the master branch allowed all tests to run and install, but when I run HelloWorld.pl it throws the error: unknown option "-commSand" at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Tk/Widget.pm line 205. So I guess I need to remove my SP-5.38.0,  find SP-5.38.2.2, and install that.

Problems solved by installing the Tk patch and upgrading to SP 5.38.2, and then fixing a typo in my HelloWorld.pl file.  Thanks everyone!

Tk-804.036 from CPAN does not build with recent versions of strawberry perl. There are patches available but no new release on cpan yet.
A patched Tk branch is on github and can be installed with the following command:
cpanm  https://github.com/Lamprecht/perl-tk.git@Strawberry-5.38-patch 


Hi.
Should this patch work for Strawberry-5.40?

Ok - I tried. Works in Strawberry-5.40.

Glad it helped you.
